# Cross-thread label countdown

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, async-await

***Short and sweet...***

I wrote a cross-thread method that displays the countdown [in seconds] of a delay on a label.

I'm fairly confident it's far from optimal, so I'm in need of that glorious optimization advice.

```
private async Task SnoozeAsync(int seconds)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => statusLabel.Text = $"Waiting {seconds - i} seconds..."));
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

await SnoozeAsync(60);
```

Comment: Is using a timer an option ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Invoke` is a *blocking* call that returns only *after* that call has competed.

That means your loop is also including the time it takes to marshal over to the GUI thread and complete.  You probably don't want that.

I would use `BeginInvoke` instead, which does not wait for the method to complete on the GUI thread.

This is also the difference between `SynchronizationContext` methods `Post` and `Send`.

I would also prevent `await` from potentially capturing the current `SynchronizationContext` using `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

To protect against exceptions if the control is disposed of (happens on form close and for other reasons) I'd add an `IsDisposed` check.

Finally I would allow this `Task` to be [cancelled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) as a matter of best practices using a `CancellationToken`.

```
private async Task SnoozeAsync(int seconds, CancellationToken token)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
        {
            if (!statusLabel.IsDisposed)
                statusLabel.Text = $"Waiting {seconds - i} seconds...";
        }));
        await Task.Delay(1000, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add in the missing closing parenthesis for BeginInvoke.